# Spring webflux on tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I just created a new application using Spring boot 2 M7 and I'm using `spring-webflux`.

I built the application as an autoexecutable war that I can start in dev with `java -jar app.war` and also on a standalone tomcat server for UAT purpose.

In the web reactive reference doc, I read

> To deploy as a WAR to a Servlet 3.1+ container, wrap HttpHandler with ServletHttpHandlerAdapter and register that as a Servlet. This can be automated through the use of AbstractReactiveWebInitializer.

Baeldung site also wrote about it and they describe a procedure to register a servlet that wrap the router for a standalone environment.

Using Spring boot tomcat starter, I didn't need to do anything : no code about booting the server necessary ; the app starts using the embedded server. In debug I saw NIO access so all seems fine.

I didn't try yet but what will happen on a standalone tomcat using Spring boot tomcat starter and webflux starter ? Is spring boot take care of everything (embbeded and standalone tomcat) ? how does it work ?

Comment: Hi, my 2 cents: I think you should try to see what happens and come back here if you bump into issues

Comment: If you have a Servlet 3.1 container, as stated by the documentation, it wil work.